# Are raw strings faster than normal strings?

Tags: c++, string, literals

I wanted to ask if raw strings are faster than normal strings at **compile-time**.

Let me explain what i mean with "raw" and "normal" strings...
We know there is a 'R' literal.

`const char * raw = R"(Hello\nWorld!)";` will output

```
Hello\nWorld!
```

`const char * normal = "Hello\nWorld!"` will output

```
Hello
World!
```

So whats actually faster? I think using the R-Literal for strings like `Hi, how are you?` is faster than the 'normal' way we use strings.

Comment: They are both resolved at compile time. So are you asking about the compile time or runtime impact?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, i'm asking about the compile time. I'm sure the R-literal is faster at compile-time than the other one, isn't it?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Why do you care? Are you planning on putting gigabytes of data into a string literal?

Comment: No, its just a question i ask myself

Comment: Raw strings literals allow you to input strings into your source code without having to mind escape sequences. They have nothing to do with program speed.

Comment: Raw [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are likely computationally more expensive to parse than regular string literals, when there aren't any escape sequences. The delimiter for raw string literals is user-defined, which precludes use of static tables for parsing.

Answer (score 2):

> So whats actually faster? I think using the R-Literal for strings like Hi, how are you? is faster than the 'normal' way we use strings.

OK, as you're asking for the compile time impact of *"normal"* or raw string literals, it could be that raw string literals can be handled faster, since the compiler won't need to handle escape character parsing and translation.

Though I believe that the difference won't be really significant.

The major advantage of raw string literals is, that you don't need to care about escaping special characters when writing the source code.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Btw, "The major advantage of raw string literals is, that you don't need to care about escaping special characters when writing the source code.", so would a R-literal fix some MySQL character issues?

Comment: @Lazcano _"so would a R-literal fix some MySQL character issues?"_ Maybe. Depends on the concrete use case.

Comment: @Lazcano> Safe answer: no. From the context, I'm 99% sure you are confusing very different cases of escaping and what they mean.

Comment: I think i really do

Answer (score 2):

Raw strings might be slightly faster or slower to parse in a particular compiler, but the difference will almost certainly be too small to notice.

The purpose of raw strings isn't to improve compilation speed.  It's to let you write string literals that contain lots of special characters (like backslashes and quotes) in a more-readable way, without having to insert lots of additional backslashes for escaping.

Use normal string literals unless your string needs lots of escaping that makes it look awkward in the source code.  Use raw string literals just for those cases.